# Parsing HTML page into CSV - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing

I am trying to transfer all the data i parsed from a website into a csv file but i have run into a couple of problems:

1.Even though i have added the character encoding, it still prints out as HTML in excel rather than plain text:

e.g

```
<option redirectvalue="/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series/ET10B">ET10B</option>
```

2.It prints out in one column rather than rows for them all

Here is my code so far:

```
import string, urllib2, urlparse, csv, sys, codecs, cStringIO
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ast import literal_eval


class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)



changable_url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All%20In%20One/E%20Series'
page = urllib2.urlopen(changable_url)
base_url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

selects = []
redirects = []
model_info = []

#Opening csv writer
c = UnicodeWriter(open(r"asus_stock.csv", "wb"))
#Object reader
cr = UnicodeWriter(open(r"asus_stock.csv", "rb"))

print "FETCHING OPTIONS"
select = soup.find(id='myselectListModel')
selects.append(select)

for item in selects:
    print item.get_text()



options = select.findAll('option')


for option in options:
    if(option.has_attr('redirectvalue')):
       redirects.append(option['redirectvalue'])

for r in redirects:
    rpage = urllib2.urlopen(urljoin(base_url, quote(r)))
    s = BeautifulSoup(rpage)
    #print s


    #Fetching the main title for each specific model and printing it out
    print "FETCHING MAIN TITLE"
    maintitle = s.find(id='puffBreadCrumbs')
    model_info.append(maintitle)
    print maintitle.get_text()

    datas = s.find(id='accordion')

    a = datas.findAll('a')

    content = datas.findAll('span')

    print "FETCHING CATEGORY"
    for data in a:

        if(data.has_attr('onclick')):
            arguments = literal_eval('(' + data['onclick'].replace(', this', '').split('(', 1)[1])
            #model_info.append(arguments)
            print arguments #arguments[1] + " " + arguments[3] + " " + arguments[4] 

    # Retrieves Part number and Price        
    print "FETCHING DATA"
    for complete in content:

        if(complete.has_attr('class')):
            #model_info.append(complete['class'])

            print complete.get_text()


    print "FETCHING IMAGES"
    img = s.find('td')

    images = img.findAll('img')
    model_info.append(images)
    print images

c.writerows(selects)
```

How can i make it so it prints out as

> 1-Text rather than HTML
>
> 2-Rows rather than one column

**[EDIT]**
This is how i would like the CSV file to be displayed and example of values to be returned

```
"Brand Name"  "CategoryID"  "ModelID"    "Family"            "Name"                  "Part Number"  "Price"  "Image src"
    Asus    |   AC Adapter  |  ET1602  |  E Series | Power Cord 3P L:80CM,UK(B) |    14G110008350   |14.77  |  image src
```

**[NEW EDIT]**

These are the outputs for the printed values:

```
print "FETCHING OPTIONS"
select = soup.find(id='myselectListModel')
selects.append(select)

for item in selects:
    print item.get_text()
```

yields:

```
ET10B ET1602 ET1602C etc..
```

Fetching Main Title:

```
print "FETCHING MAIN TITLE"
maintitle = s.find(id='puffBreadCrumbs')
model_info.append(maintitle)
print maintitle.get_text()
```

yields:

> Asus - All In One - E Series - ET10B

Fetching Category

```
datas = s.find(id='accordion')

a = datas.findAll('a')

content = datas.findAll('span')

print "FETCHING CATEGORY"
for data in a:

    if(data.has_attr('onclick')):
        arguments = literal_eval('(' + data['onclick'].replace(', this', '').split('(', 1)[1])
        #model_info.append(arguments)
        print arguments
```

yields:

```
FETCHING CATEGORY
('Asus', 'AC Adapter', 'ET10B', '6941', 'E Series')
('Asus', '04G265003580')
('Asus', '14G110008340')
('Asus', 'Bracket', 'ET10B', '7138', 'E Series')
('Asus', 'Cable', 'ET10B', '6983', 'E Series')
('Asus', 'Camera', 'ET10B', '6985', 'E Series')
('Asus', 'Cooling', 'ET10B', '6999', 'E Series')
('Asus', 'Cover', 'ET10B', '6984', 'E Series') 
etc..
```

Fetching the Name:

```
print "FETCHING NAME"
name = s.find('b').get_text()
print name
```

yields:

> POWER ADAPTER 65W19V 3PIN

Fetching Part Number and Price

```
print "FETCHING PART NUMBER AND PRICE (inc. VAT)"
for complete in content:

   if(complete.has_attr('class')):
        #model_info.append(complete['class'])
        print complete.get_text()
```

yields:

```
FETCHING PART NUMBER AND PRICE (inc. VAT)
Part number: 04G265003580


Remote stock
38.09:- EUR
```

Fetching the images

```
print "FETCHING IMAGES"
img = s.find('td')

images = img.findAll('img')
model_info.append(images)
print images
```

yields:

```
FETCHING IMAGES
[<img alt="" src="/images/Articles/thumbs/04G265003580_thumb.jpg"/>]
```

Comment: And what data do you expect to find in each column? You are writing the `selects` list to CSV, which are just BeautifulSoup Element objects.

Comment: please take a look at my edit

Comment: Can you add a `print` statement somewhere that shows how to get each column of that data?

Comment: PLease take a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the `selects` list further; rather than write the whole list to the CSV file, write just the `option` tags to the CSV file:

```
for select in selects:
    c.writerow([opt.string for opt in select.find_all('option')])
```

Comment: @ash: Are you saying `selects` is empty?